# 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. after install jupyter also

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently degraded my python from 3.10 to 3.9 as few of the libraries were not working, specifically I was facing issue with jupyter installation. However since degradation of my python my jupyter command is not working as an example:
I am trying to convert my .ipynb file in .py with following code.

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script 'test.ipynb'
or jupyter nbconvert --to script 'test.ipynb'
```

or trying to enable nbextension with following code

```
!jupyter nbextension enable 
or !jupyter nbextension enable
```

I am getting an error which says:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed,

```
pip install jupyter
pip install jupyter notebook
```

not sure what else it is looking for. I am able to open my jupyter notebook and work. No problem there. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to install Jupyter Notebook:

1. First, uninstall jupyter by `pip uninstall jupyter`.
2. Then, install jupyter through `pip install --upgrade jupyter ipython`.

Comment: I followed the step, didn't work.same problem.

Comment: What's your pip version?

Comment: pip 21.3 from c:\python\python 39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Comment: Did the installation complete without any errors?

Comment: everything completed without any error